# Toggle ExpandAll/CollapseAll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using jQuery toggle to toggle between show and hide. It works perfectly fine for individual elements. When I try to do a expand all and collapse all it works fine for all the condition except one. If any individual element is already expanded or collapsed it does toggle them but not as expected. That is, when I click on expand all it expands all the elements except the individual element which is already expanded get collapsed and vice-versa. How do I take care of this condition?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".toggle_container").hide();
    $("div.description-content-title").toggle(function () {
        $(this).addClass("collArrow");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("collArrow");
    });
    $("div.description-content-title").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
    });

    $(".close-all").toggle(function () {
        $(".close-all a").text("[Expand All]");
    }, function () {
        $(".close-all a").text("[Close All]");
    });

    $(".close-all").click(function () {
        $(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="news-top-head">
    <div class="time-head sortable" data-sort-column="ContentDate">
        <span style="float: left; width: auto;">Time</span> <span class="sort-order-hidden ui-icon" />
    </div>
    <div class="description-head sortable" data-sort-column="ContentTitle">
        <span style="float: left; width: auto;">Description</span> <span class="sort-order-hidden ui-icon" />
    </div>
    <div class="close-all">
        <a href="#">close all</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="description-content">
    <div class="description-content-title expArrow"><%=breakingNews[index].ContentTitle%></div>
        <div class="toggle_container">
            <p ><%=breakingNews[index].ContentDescription%></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have any code sample it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use toggle for your close-all button in that case unless you add an extra class to something to figure out which the odd one out is and ignore it. Easiest way to make this work is to use `slideDown(`) and `slideUp()` instead of `slideToggle()`. Remove the following code:

```
$(".close-all").click(function () {
    $(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

And change:

```
$(".close-all").toggle(function () {
    $(".close-all a").text("[Expand All]");
}, function () {
    $(".close-all a").text("[Close All]");

});
```

To:

```
$(".close-all").toggle(function () {
    $(".close-all a").text("[Expand All]");
    $(".toggle_container").slideDown("slow");
}, function () {
    $(".close-all a").text("[Close All]");
    $(".toggle_container").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: Paul: When All the element is expanded and the text is close ALL and when i click on the close all tab it does not close the elements. Only the text toggle backs to expand All. when all the text are closed and expand all is clicked it expands all the elements correctly and toggles the text back to close all.

Comment: @Pawan, I updated my post. It was caused by the toggle() handler firing before the click() handler. I put the logic for slideUp and slideDown into the toggle() handlers now.

Comment: hey Paul, i updated my code jquery script to one shown below. but now its not detecting my collapse all click for the first time. When i click the second time it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code if useful,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#toggle_container").hide();
});
function showSlidingDiv(){
    $("#toggle_container").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 500 });
}
```

Also can refer to [Show-Hide div content using jQuery](http://chandreshmaheshwari.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/show-hide-div-content-using-jquery/) if required..